# Typescript React/ styled-components - passing function as prop to component throws error on missing type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm getting an error of overload match but I didn't understand because isn't getting this error yesterday error in this happens too when I try to add another onClick function in another component or order page

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5YJm.png)

code;

```
import React, { MouseEventHandler } from 'react'

import { Container, Image } from './styles'

interface ImageFullscreen {
  path?: string
  shown: boolean
  close: MouseEventHandler
}

const ImageFullscreen: React.FC<ImageFullscreen> = ({
  path = 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080?text=Imagem+Placeholder+Das+Postagens',
  close,
  shown,
}) => {
  const handleMapViewClose: MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = e => {
    const source = (e.target as HTMLDivElement & HTMLImageElement).src
    if (source === undefined) {
      close(e)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Container display={shown} onClick={handleMapViewClose}>
      <Image src={path} alt='ImageFullscreen' />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ImageFullscreen
```

code of container

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { fadeIn } from 'styles/keyframes'

interface Container {
  display: boolean
}

export const Container = styled.div<Container>`
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: ${props => (props.display ? 'flex' : 'none')};
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
  animation: ${fadeIn} 500ms 1;
`

export const Image = styled.img`
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
`
```

Comment: could you provide us the code of this container? maybe is the way that you are creating the style-component
thanks

Comment: sorry, i added the container creation

Comment: so, is it working now?

Comment: no the same, i added the container creation in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem in the name of your interface, it's the same of your Component, maybe you can change the name and it will works.

something like this:

```
interface IContainer {
  display: boolean
}
export const Container = styled.div<IContainer>`...`
```

Comment: That might be true! Lucas's styled component 'Container' is named the same as the interface 'Container'

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, if you try

```
const handleMapViewClose = ( e : React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement> ) => {
    const source = (e.target as HTMLDivElement & HTMLImageElement).src
    if (source === undefined) {
      close(e)
    }
  }
```

Does it work?

---

I think you misspelled the event iterface name maybe?